# Can't make chart js responsive

Tags: javascript, chart.js, responsive

sorry if I missed anything to fix my issue, I've read and tried many solutions without any of them being adapted to the problem.

I have several charts (from chart.js) on a single page, but I can't succeed to make them responsive, despite :

```
responsive: true,
```

The best responsive display I could get was when enlarging canvas width and height, but on the desktop version charts were displayed the entire screen.

Here is a [fiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/blueagency/czw8htza/)

Anybody to help me ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is :

**1. add a div around the canvas**

for example :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <canvas width="600" height="250"></canvas>
</div>
```

**2. add height to the div class in the css**

```
.wrapper {
height: 500px !important;
}
```

(adjust height as you wish the responsive rendering)

Comment: This won't work as described. The parent will be 500px height, but the graph itself won't be. Even if you force the canvas to be 500px min-height, it will just distort the graph and won't actually render as expected.

The correct solution is to add the below within the graph options:


```options: {
     responsive:true,
     maintainAspectRatio: false // this is the important line
}```

Answer (score 21):

`maintainAspectRatio: false` sorted me out on a similar problem. The default value is `true`.

Comment: This should be much more clear in the documentation!

Comment: Doesn't even make sense why this works /:

Comment: The document now has [the section](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note) that explains this situation.

Answer (score 11):

Bootstrap has an example page, which has a chart (using chartjs) that is responsive. So, I would point to that URL, which can be downloaded and we have a responsive chart.

[Dasbhoard Example showing Reponsive Chart](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/)

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old post, but recently came across it.

Please check
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#important-note

It basically says that,

1. Detecting when the canvas size changes can not be done directly from the canvas element. Chart.js uses its parent container to update the canvas render and display sizes. However, this method requires the container to be relatively positioned and dedicated to the chart canvas only. Responsiveness can then be achieved by setting relative values for the container size".
2. Note that in order for the above code to correctly resize the chart height, the maintainAspectRatio option must also be set to false."

For Example,

```
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: It was the "maintainAspectRatio: false" that I missed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can make the container divs responsive using CSS and make svg `width: 100%` and `height:100%`

Here is updated fiddle [fiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/czw8htza/2/)

Comment: It creates 1 column of text and charts on the left of the page.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar situation and based on [chartjs documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html) I had to add `responsive: true` in my `options` section, but it didn't solve my problem! Finally I noticed that parent element of `canvas` is `flexbox`! Removing that solved my problem!

P.S Official documentation says that adding some style or width/height attributes to canvas tag is invalid! Below is snippet from docs

> The following examples do not work:
>
> `<canvas height="40vh" width="80vw">`: invalid values, the canvas
>   doesn't resize (example) `<canvas style="height:40vh; width:80vw">`:
>   invalid behavior, the canvas is resized but becomes blurry

Hope my answer can help someone!

Comment: thanks :) same here. removing `display: flex` helped

Answer (score 5):

As I saw in fiddle, you have given fixed height and width to canvas tag.

Try to give both height and width 70% or 80% for canvas tag. This may solve your problem.

100% may be give full large charts bt try to limit them to 70 to 80.

Comment: I've tried width/height in percentage but the issue is the same.

Comment: Try to limit the corresponding div in fixed height and width and canvas in percentage. This may help. @BlueAgency

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving height and width attribute, set them through style:

`<canvas id="myChart" style="height: 20rem"></canvas>`

Answer (score 1):

I've found that with Chart.js, you need a containing div where you manipulate the css(height/width), which will help the responsiveness - but not fully. There are some constraints especially with the width, as the containing div might leave a lot of whitespace on the bottom/sides, since the canvas won't fully adjust to the containing width as a percentage.  It isn't perfect, but it works.

So, as a solution: Make a containing div for each chart, and place it using CSS styles for this div :)

Comment: My charts are displayed in groups of 2 on my page. Each group is wrapped in a div container as I use Bootstrap, then each chart is in a div "class=row". I tried to apply to these different divs width and height in percentage, and even max-width and max-height, but nothing works.

Comment: Can you make a containing div for the two rows that has width/height=100%, and then divide it down on two containing divs - one for each component?

Comment: You mean `<div class="container" width="100%" height="100%"><div class="container"><div class="row"><canvas id="myChart1" width="600" height="250"></canvas></div></div><div class="container"><div class="row"><canvas id="myChart2" width="600" height="250"></canvas></div></div><script type="text/javascript">...</script></div>` ?? No better display...

Comment: No, sorry if I'm not concise. You remove the width/height from the canvas itself, and only apply it to the parent div of each canvas as a percentage. Might wanna try adding display: inline-block; to the canvasses themselves.

Comment: I tried this, but no improvement. I even tried to apply a class to canvas when `@media screen and (max-width: 479px)` but nothing works, I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

i tried all what the documents said but no chance,so i managed by my self:

```
<section style="padding: 0px">    
 <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; margin: auto; height:167px; width: 1492px;">
         <canvas id="Graph"></canvas>
     </div>
 </section>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
      $( window ).resize(function() {
         $('#Graph').closest('.chart-container').css('width',$('#Graph').closest('section').width());
      });
    });
    </script>
```

the idea here to change the width or the height or both when the window resized.

Answer (score 0):

Because of can't use media queries to set `width` and `height`, I set width and height attribute by detect mobile or desktop, like below

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="chart" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}"></canvas>
```

**javascript - angularjs**

```
$scope.width = '';
$scope.height = '120';
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
   $scope.width = '100';
   $scope.height = '100';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[from chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.2/general/responsive.html)

> Responsiveness can then be achieved by setting relative values for the
> container size:
>
> ```
> <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
>     <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
> </div>
> ```
>
> The chart can also be programmatically resized by modifying the
> container size: `chart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = '128px';`

Answer (score 0):

None of the Chartjs configuration options worked for me. I ended up setting the canvas width to 100%, and it worked like a charm.

```css
.w-100 {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mychart" class="chart-canvas w-100"></canvas>
```