# How to make three column layout with widgets the height the same as the width with bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a Dashboard Page with 3 widgets on it in a row. (They are charts). I want to make them responsive.  The charts take their size based on the parent container. I want the three widgets to take up the full width of the screen, and then the height should equal the width.

How do I achieve that using bootstrap 4? I am ok with using JS if that is required

Comment: Do you want three squares in a row (height = own width), or three vertical rectangles making a square (height = total width)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap `div.row` with three `div.col.p-0` then set the height of the charts relative to the viewport width with the `vw` unit (33.33vw for square aspect)

```css
.square-charts canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33vw;
}

.rect-charts canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row square-charts">
    <div class="col p-0">
      <canvas id="Chart1"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-0">
      <canvas id="Chart2"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-0">
      <canvas id="Chart3"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row rect-charts">
    <div class="col p-0">
      <canvas id="Chart6"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-0">
      <canvas id="Chart5"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-0">
      <canvas id="Chart6"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340342/cant-make-chart-js-responsive) question i think that person shares your problem.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't answer the question.  The link is to a site that offers charts. What I want to do is make the charts responsive which requires that the height corresponds to the width.  Bootstrap sets the width correctly, but the height I have not figured out yet.